# How do I read in .mat files from a list?

Tags: r

I'm trying to read in all .mat files from a folder. I'm using this line of code to do so:

```
setwd("filepath")
filenames <- list.files("filepath", recursive=TRUE)
d <- readMat(filenames)
```

But this is what I get in the RStudio console:

```
Error in file(con, open = "rb") : invalid 'description' argument
```

Comment: As an initial troubleshooting step, double check the names present in your `filenames` object. Be sure that there are no filenames in there that do not correspond to a .mat file

Comment: I think `readMat()` expects a file name for its first argument, not a list. You may be able to read the files into a list using something like `d <- lapply(filenames, function(x) readMat(x))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer, since it seems to have solved the issue.

I think readMat() expects a file name for its first argument, not a list. You may be able to read the files into a list using something like:

```
d <- lapply(filenames, function(x) readMat(x))
```